# How to make <deletechar> behave as <backspace> in Emacs overwrite mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

When pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> in Emacs `overwrite` mode, the following character is deleted. However, when pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> the previous character is not deleted but replaced with a space.

How can I make <kbd>Delete</kbd> (bound to `delete-forward-char`) behave the same way? That is, pressing  <kbd>Delete</kbd> in `overwrite` mode should move the cursor to right and replace the character under the cursor with a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>Space</kbd> instead.

If <kbd>Delete</kbd> did what you want, there would not have been a way to remove empty space (other than `delete-region`).

Comment: Thanks, actually I will seldom need to delete empty space, so I think I end up just rebinding the Delete key to act as the space key..